# For root access composer not found in centos 7

Tags: terminal, centos, package, composer-php, centos7

I installed composer in centos 7.
When I logged in with centos user, if I hit `composer -v`, it shows that composer is installed.
But after I switch to root access with `sudo su`, if I hit `composer -v`, it displays not found.
Can anyone help me? What should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe are the symptoms of non-packaged install.

If something is available from packages, you should strive to install it using packages where available.

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install composer
# have no problems, have a cup of coffee
```

Comment: Great! It worked. Thank you. So should I remove  old installed composer?

Comment: How can I remove it?

Comment: I can only guess how you installed prior to this. Check for it in `/usr/local/bin/composer` or `/root/.local/bin/composer`. Remove either of the files if found.

Comment: Great! Thanks I removed! You made my day!